# What is the difference between 'let' and 'const' ECMAScript 2015 (ES6)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-6

I'm wondering what is the difference between `let` and `const` in **ES6**. Both of them are block scoped, as the example in the following code:

```
const PI = 3.14;
console.log(PI);

PI = 3;
console.log(PI);

const PI = 4;
console.log(PI);

var PI = 5;
console.log(PI);
```

In ES5 the output will be:

```
3.14
3.14
3.14
3.14
```

But in ES6 it will be:

```
3.14
3
4
5
```

I'm wondering why **ES6** allows the change of `const` value, the question is why should we use 'const' now? we can use 'let' instead?

**Note**: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nularebi/2/edit) can be used for testing, choose **JavaScript** to run **ES5** code and **Traceur** to run it with **ES6** capabilities.

Comment: The spec is still under development, let alone implementations. My chrome;32.0.* is silent if you redefine const, but it stays constant. How did you test your code?

Comment: I am not sure about ESMAScript6 terminology, but in other languages, that would not count as "chang[ing] of const value", it would *shadow* a constant binding with a different binding.

Comment: @iccthedral: I JSBin -> choose Javascript to run ECMAScript5 code and Traceur to run it with ECMAScript6 capabilities.

Comment: Maybe show the code that Traceur genererates - probably it's buggy. Notice that your example would not run at all in ES5 if it was implemented strictly, so you're just experiencing the current browser support of `const` - some browsers are just treating at as a `var` for example.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What you're seeing is just an implementation mistake. According to the [ES6 spec wiki on `const`](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aconst), `const` is:

> A initialize-once, read-only thereafter binding form is useful and has
>   precedent in existing implementations, in the form of const
>   declarations.

It's meant to be read-only, just like it currently is. The ES6 implementation of `const` in Traceur and Continuum are buggy (they probably just overlooked it)

Here's a [Github issue regarding Traceur not implementing `const`](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/issues/18)

Answer (score 73):

The difference between `let` and `const` is that once you bind a value/object to a variable using `const`, you can't reassign to that variable. In other words Example:

```
const something = {};
something = 10; // Error.

let somethingElse = {};
somethingElse = 1000; // This is fine.
```

The question details claim that this is a change from ES5 — this is actually a misunderstanding. Using `const` in a browser that only supports ECMAScript 5 will always throw an error. The `const` statement did not exist in ECMAScript 5. The behaviour in  is either JS Bin being misleading as to what type of JavaScript is being run, or it’s a browser bug.

In practice, browsers didn't just go from 0% support for ECMAScript 2015 (ECMAScript 6) to 100% in one go — features are added bit-by-bit until the browser is fully compliant. What JS Bin calls ‘JavaScript’ just means whatever ECMAScript features your browser currently supports — it doesn’t mean ‘ES5’ or ‘ES6’ or anything else. Many browsers supported `const` and `let` before they fully supported ES6, but some (like Firefox) treated `const` like `let` for some time. It is likely that the question asker’s browser supported `let` and `const` but did not implement them correctly.

Secondly, tools like Babel and Traceur do not make ES6 ‘run’ in an older browser — they instead turn ES6 code into ES5 that does approximately the same thing. Traceur is likely turning `const` statements into `var` statements, but I doubt it is always enforcing that the semantics of a `const` statement are exactly replicated in ES5. Using JS Bin to run ES6 using Traceur is not going to give exactly the same results as running ES6 in a fully ES6 specification-compliant browser.

---

It is important to note that `const` does not make a value or object immutable.

```
const myArray = [];
myArray.push(1); // Works fine.
myArray[1] = 2; // Also works fine.
console.log(myArray); // [1, 2]
myArray = [1, 2, 3] // This will throw.
```

Probably the best way to make an object (shallowly) immutable at the moment is to use `Object.freeze()` on it. However, this only makes the object itself read-only; the values of the object’s properties can still be mutated.

Comment: So I am still confused here: 1) If `const` does not make something immutable then why is it called const? 2) If you can reassign the value using `let`, then how is it different from `var`?
I would appreciate some clarification here. Sorry more I read on this more I am getting confused to identify a clear distinction among these.

Comment: @rohan-patel 1) `const` is making the binding (or ‘link’) between the name of a variable and an object constant. If you use `const`, that variable name will *always* reference the same object. 2) `let` is block-scoped, while `var` is function-scoped. In other words, if you use `let` inside an if-statement the variable will only exist inside the if-statement, while if you used `var`, the variable would exist within the body of the function that the if-statement was in.

Comment: @rohan-patel As for why these two things are useful: if you know a variable name only ever gets assigned to an object once and isn’t changed, it makes your code a lot easier read and think about. As for `let`, `let` works the way variables work in most other programming languages, as opposed to `var`, which doesn't.

Comment: Very annoying coming from a swift background. Let is supposed to declare non-changing properties.

Comment: @Jonny I’m sure it is. ES6/JavaScript does have a lot of constraints programming-language-design-wise which Swift doesn’t have, and in my opinion Swift’s ‘var’ vs ‘let’ distinction isn’t as intuitive itself as Rust’s ‘let mutable’ notation.

Answer (score 12):

## The `let` and `const`

ES6 `let` allows you to declare a variable that is limited in scope to the block (Local variable). The main difference is that the scope of a `var` variable is the entire enclosing function:

```
if (true) {
  var foo = 42; // scope globally
}

console.log(foo); // 42
```

### The `let` Scope

```
if (true) {
  let foo = 42; // scoped in block
}

console.log(foo); // ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

Using `var` in function scope is the same as using `let`:

```
function bar() {
  var foo = 42; // scoped in function
}

console.log(foo); // ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

The `let` keyword attaches the variable declaration to the scope of whatever block it is contained in.

### Declaration Order

Another difference between `let` and `var` is the declaration/initialization order. Accessing a variable declared by `let` earlier than its declaration causes a **ReferenceError**.

```
console.log(a); // undefined
console.log(b); // ReferenceError: b is not defined
  
var a = 1;
let b = 2;
```

### Using `const`

On the other hand, using ES6 `const` is much like using the `let`, but once a value is assigned, it cannot be changed. Use `const` as an immutable value to prevent the variable from accidentally re-assigned:

```
const num = 42;

try {
  num = 99;
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
  // TypeError: invalid assignment to const `number'

}

num; // 42
```

Use `const` to assign variables that are constant in real life (e.g. freezing temperature). JavaScript `const` is not about making unchangeable values, it has nothing to do with the value, `const` is to prevent re-assigning another value to the variable and make the variable as read-only. However, values can be always changed:

```
const arr = [0, 1, 2];
arr[3] = 3; // [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

To prevent value change, use `Object.freeze()`:

```
let arr = Object.freeze([0, 1, 2]);
arr[0] = 5;

arr; // [0, 1, 2]
```

### Using `let` With `For` Loop

A particular case where `let` is really shines, is in the header of `for` loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}

// 0 1 2 3 4 5

console.log(i); // ReferenceError, great! i is not global
```

Answer (score 10):

## let

- Use block scope in programming.
- for every block let create its own new scope which you cannot access in outside of that block.
- value can be changed as many times as you want.
- let is extremely useful to have for the vast majority of code. It can greatly enhance your code readability and decrease the chance of a programming error.

  ```
  let abc = 0;

  if(true)
   abc = 5 //fine

  if(true){
    let def = 5
  }
  console.log(def)
  ```

## const

- It allows you to be immutable with variables.
- const is a good practice for both readability and maintainability and avoids using magic literals e.g.

  ```
  // Low readability
  if (x > 10) {
  }

  //Better!
  const maxRows = 10;
  if (x > maxRows) {
   }
  ```
- const declarations must be initialized

  ```
   const foo; // ERROR: const declarations must be initialized
  ```

> - A const is block scoped like we saw with let:+

```
const foo = 123;
if (true) {
    const foo = 456; // Allowed as its a new variable limited to this `if` block
}
```

Answer (score 5):

### Summary:

Both the `let` and the `const` keyword are ways to declare **block scoped** variables. There is one big difference though:

- Variables declared with `let` can be reassigned.
- Variables declared with `const` have to be initialized when declared and can't be reassigned.

If you try to reassign variables with declared with the `const` keyword you will get the following error (chrome devtools):

[image: const reassignment error]

### Why should we use this?

If we know that we want to assign a variable once and that we don't want to reassign the variable, using the `const` keywords offers the following advantages:

- We communicate in our code that we don't want to reassign the variable. This way if other programmmers look to your code (or even you to your own code you wrote a while ago) you know that the variables which are declared with `const` should not be reassigned. This way our code becomes more declarative and easier to work with.
- We force the principle of not being able to reassign a variable (JS engine throws error). This way if you accidentally try to reassign a variable which is not meant to be reassigned you can detect this at an earlier stage (because it's logged to the console).

### Caveat:

Although a variable declared with `const` can't be reassigned this doesn't mean that an assigned object isn't mutable. For example:

```js
const obj = {prop1: 1}

// we can still mutate the object assigned to the 
// variable declared with the const keyword
obj.prop1 = 10;
obj.prop2 = 2;

console.log(obj);
```

If you also want your object to be non mutable you can use `Object.freeze()` in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

**let and const**

Variables declared with `let` and `const` eliminate specific issue of hoisting because they’re scoped to the block, not to the function.

If a variable is declared using `let` or `const` inside a block of code (denoted by curly braces { }), then the variable is stuck in what is known as the temporal dead zone until the variable’s declaration is processed. This behavior prevents variables from being accessed only until after they’ve been declared.

**Rules for using let and const**

`let` and `const` also have some other interesting properties.

- Variables declared with `let` can be reassigned, but can’t be
  redeclared in the same scope.
- Variables declared with `const` must be assigned an initial value, but
  can’t be redeclared in the same scope, and can’t be reassigned.

**Use cases**

The big question is when should you use `let` and `const`? The general rule of thumb is as follows:

- use `let` when you plan to reassign new values to a variable, and
- use `const` when you don’t plan on reassigning new values to a
  variable.

Since `const` is the strictest way to declare a variable, it is suggest that you always declare variables with `const` because it'll make your code easier to reason about since you know the identifiers won't change throughout the lifetime of your program. If you find that you need to update a variable or change it, then go back and switch it from `const` to `let`.

Answer (score 1):

- var declarations are globally scoped or function scoped while let and
  const are block scoped.
- var variables can be updated and re-declared within its scope; let
  variables can be updated but not re-declared;const variables can neither be updated nor re-declared.
- They are all hoisted to the top of their scope. But while var
  variables are initialized with undefined, let and const variables are
  not initialized.
- While var and let can be declared without being initialized, const
  must be initialized during declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some notes that I took that helped me on this subject.  Also comparing `const` and `let` to `var`.

Here's about `var`:

```
// Var
// 1. var is hoisted to the top of the function, regardless of block
// 2. var can be defined as last line and will be hoisted to top of code block
// 3. for undefined var //output error is 'undefined' and code continues executing
// 4. trying to execute function with undefined variable
// Example: // log(myName); // output: ReferenceError: myName is not defined and code stops executing
```

Here's about `let` and `const`:

```
// Let and Const
// 1. use `const` to declare variables which won't change
// 2. `const` is used to initialize-once, read-only thereafter
// 3. use `let` to declare variables which will change
// 4. `let` or `const` are scoped to the "block", not the function
// 5. trying to change value of const and then console.logging result will give error
// const ANSWER = 42;
// ANSWER = 3.14159;
// console.log(ANSWER);
// Error statement will be "TypeError: Assignment to constant variable." and code will stop executing
// 6. `let` won't allow reference before definition
// function letTest2 () {
//   log(b);
//   let b = 3;}
// Error statement will be "ReferenceError: b is not defined." and code will stop executing
```

Answer (score 0):

**Var**

```
The var keyword was introduced with JavaScript. 
It has global scope.    
It can be declared globally and can be accessed globally.   
Variable declared with var keyword can be re-declared and updated in the same scope.
Example:
function varGreeter(){
  var a = 10;        
  var a = 20; //a is replaced
  console.log(a);
}
varGreeter();
```

It is hoisted.

```
Example:
{
  console.log(c); // undefined. 
  //Due to hoisting
  var c = 2;
}
```

**Let**

```
The let keyword was added in ES6 (ES 2015) version of JavaScript.
It is limited to block scope.
It can be declared globally but cannot be accessed globally.
Variable declared with let keyword can be updated but not re-declared.
Example:
function varGreeter(){
  let a = 10;        
 let a = 20; //SyntaxError: 
 //Identifier 'a' has already been declared
  console.log(a);
}
varGreeter();
```

It is not hoisted.

```
Example:
{
  console.log(b); // ReferenceError: 
  //b is not defined
  let b = 3;
}
```

Global object property

```
  var no1 = "123";  // globally scoped
  let no2 = "789"; // globally scoped

  console.log(window.no1); // 123
  console.log(window.no2); // undefined
```

Redeclaration:

'use strict';

```
  var name= "Keshav";
  var name= "Keshav Gera"; // No problem, 'name' is replaced.

  let surname= "Rahul Kumar";
  let surname= "Rahul Khan "; // SyntaxError: Identifier 'surname' has already been declared
```

Hoisting

```
function run() {
    console.log(name); // undefined
    var name= "Keshav";
    console.log(name); // Keshav
}

 run();

 function checkHoisting() {
     console.log(name); // ReferenceError
     let name= "Keshav";
     console.log(name); // Keshav
 }
 checkHoisting();
```

**Note**: in case of var, you will get undefined, in case of let you will get reference error

**Const**

```
It allows you to be immutable with variables.
```

Const declarations must be initialized

```
const name; // ERROR: const declarations must be initialized

A const is block scoped like we saw with let:+

const num = 10;
if (true) {
 const num = 20; // Allowed as its a new variable limited to this `if` block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
// declaration of const in same block scope is not allowed
const a = 10;
const a = 15; //Redeclaration of const a Error
console.log(`const outer value `+a);
*/

/*
//declaration of const in different block scope is allowed
const a = 10;
console.log(`outer value of a `+a)
{
    const a = 15; //Redeclaration of const allowed in different block scope
    console.log(`ineer value of a `+a);
}
*/

/*
// re assigning const variable in any block scope is not allowed
const a = 10;
a = 15; //invalid assignment to const 'a'
{
    a = 15;  //invalid assignment to const 'a'
}
*/

/*
// let also can not be re declared in the same block scope
let a = 10;
let a = 15; //SyntaxError: redeclaration of let a
*/

/*
// let can be redeclared in different block scope
let a = 10;
{
    let a = 15; //allowed.
}
*/

/*
// let can be re assigned in same block or different block
let a = 10;
a = 15; //allowed for let but for const its not allowed.
*/

/*
let a = 10;
{
    a = 15; //allowed
}
*/
```

Comment: Didn't address the problem at all. Also, don't use comment in your code if it is unnecessary. Only use comment for code that will result in error or use them for actual comments. The problem was already well answered years ago so there is also no need to add this answer as it doesn't provide any extra information to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Majourly there are 3 differences :

1. Let cannot be redeclared while var can support and it will assign last declared value.
2. Hoisting

   str="prod"
   console.log(str)
   var str
   //
   str2="prod",
   console.log(str2),
   // let str2 (not allowed)
3. Global and local scope :

var can be accessible outside of local but let has only local scope outside scope it will not work,