# Why added value en each loop hasn't been stored on next iteration?

Tags: cypress, cypress-each

Brief logic is the next: after clicking on 'li' element, request is sent, and based on response value of 'contacts', it should select if it's greater than 0, once such element is find, i need to break each loop. But currently, despite I set value, which should break each loop on next iteration (returns false). count[] has been restored with old values, what's an issue?

```js
    cy.get('div[id=company_select]').then($el => {

        const count = []
        cy.wrap($el).click().find('li').each((element, index) => {
            cy.intercept('GET', '**/company/view-json**').as('getCompanyProps')

            cy.log(count.length)
            if (count.length > 0) {
                return false
            } else {
                cy.wrap(element).click().wait('@getCompanyProps').then((interception) => {
                    if (interception.response.body.contacts.length === 0) {
                        cy.wrap($el).find('button[vs__clear]').click()
                    } else {
                        count.push(1)
                        cy.log(count.length)
                    }
                })
            }
        })

    })
```

[image: cy log]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't early-exit with `return false` in this scenario, but you can use `count` to prevent inner execution after `body.contacts.length > 0`.

```js
cy.intercept('GET', '**/company/view-json**').as('getCompanyProps') // this can be here

cy.get('div[id=company_select]').then($el => {

  const count = []
  cy.wrap(count).as('count')   // make an alias value of the count variable

  cy.wrap($el).click().find('li')
    .each((element, index) => {

      cy.get('@count').then(count => {  // retrieve count asynchronously
        if (count.length === 0) {       // no result yet?
                
          cy.wrap(element).click().wait('@getCompanyProps')
            .then((interception) => {
              if (interception.response.body.contacts.length === 0) {
                cy.wrap($el).find('button[vs__clear]').click()
              } else {
                count.push(1)
                console.log(count.length)
              }
            })
        }
      })
    })
})
```

---

The reason for this behaviour is the mixture of asynchronous commands like  `.wait('@getCompanyProps')` and synchronous code for checking the early exit.

If you use `console.log()` instead of `cy.log()` to debug the values, you'll see the logs before the early exit all run before the logs after `count.push(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you wish to know why on the second pass of your cypress each loop `cy.wrap($el).click().find('li').each((element, index) => {` the `cy.log(count.length)` is equal to 0.

Even though further down inside another then loop `cy.wrap(element).click().wait('@getCompanyProps').then((interception) => {` you increase count by `count.push(1)` and right after `cy.log(count.length)` which returns 1.

The short answer is scope. If you change a variable within a cypress loop to return that variable you need to add something like this after `.then( () =>{ cy.wrap(count)}` My solution is below but I also changed the position of your `const count = []` if you want to know why I suggest reading [What is the difference between 'let' and 'const' ECMAScript 2015 (ES6)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22308071/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-const-ecmascript-2015-es6)

```
const count = []
cy.intercept('GET', '**/company/view-json**').as('getCompanyProps')
cy.get('div[id="company_select"]')
.then( ($el) => {
  cy.wrap($el)
  .click()
  .find('li')
  .each( ($el) => {
    if (count.length === 0){
        cy.wrap($el)
        .click()
        .wait('@getCompanyProps')
        .then((interception) => {
            if (interception.response.body.contacts.length === 0) {
            cy.wrap($el)
            .find('button[vs__clear]')
            .click()
            } else {
            count.push(1)
            cy.log(count.length)
            }
          })
        }
      })
      .then( () =>{
        cy.wrap(count).as('count')
    })
})
cy.get('@count')
.then( (count) =>{
  cy.log(count.length)
})
```